# How to provide parameter input for interaction variable in H2OGradientBoostingEstimator?

Tags: h2o, interaction, multilabel-classification, gbm

I need to use the interaction variable feature of multiclass classification in `H2OGradientBoostingEstimator` in H2O in Python. I am not sure which parameter to use & how to use that. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Currently, I am using the below code -

```
pros_gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(nfolds=0,seed=1234, keep_cross_validation_predictions = False, ntrees=10, max_depth=3, learn_rate=0.01, distribution='multinomial')
hist_gbm = pros_gbm.train(x=predictors, y=target, training_frame=hf_train, validation_frame = hf_test,verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GBM inherently creates interactions.  You can extract information about feature interactions using the `.feature_interaction()` extractor method (for an H2O Model).  More information is provided in the [user guide](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm.html#gbm-feature-interactions) and the Python [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html#h2o.model.ModelBase.feature_interaction).

If you want to explicitly add a new column that is the interaction between two numerics, you could create that manually by multiplying the two (or more) columns together to get a new interaction column.

For categorical interactions, there's also the the `h2o.interaction()` method in Python [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html#h2o.H2OFrame.interaction) to create interaction columns in the data (prior to sending it to the GBM or any algorithm).

Comment: h2o.interactions()  is Categorical Interaction Feature Creation in H2O, whereas i am looking for interaction for continuous features.

Comment: GBMs are able to find (non-linear) interactions on their own and you thus typically do not need to explicitly specify interactions. This is why H2O GBM has no such parameter (as opposed to H2O GLM which does have this parameter). If you do feel like your model would benefit from interactions - you can create them explicitly by modifying the training frame, eg. hf_train["int_1"] = hf_train["feature_1"] * hf_train["feature_2"]

Comment: Getting this error while fetching interaction information by ".feature_interaction()" in python -
AttributeError: type object 'ModelBase' has no attribute 'feature_interaction'
please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: What version of H2O are you using? Feature interactions were added to GBM and XGBoost in H2O 3.32.0.2 (https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Changes.md#zermelo-33202---11172020)